# Updating custom component's form after getting a response

Tags: vue.js, laravel-spark

I'm trying to load in a Tutor's profile in a custom component with Laravel Spark. It updates with whatever I enter no problem, but the  is always empty when loaded.

The component itself is as follows:

```
Vue.component('tutor-settings', {

data() {
    return {
        tutor: [],

        updateTutorProfileForm: new SparkForm({
            profile: ''
        })
    };
},

created() {
    this.getTutor();

    Bus.$on('updateTutor', function () {
        this.updateTutorProfileForm.profile = this.tutor.profile;
    });
},

mounted() {
    this.updateTutorProfileForm.profile = this.tutor.profile;
},

methods: {
    getTutor() {
        this.$http.get('/tutor/current')
            .then(response => {
                Bus.$emit('updateTutor');
                this.tutor = response.data;
            });
    },

    updateTutorProfile() {
        Spark.put('/tutor/update/profile', this.updateTutorProfileForm)
            .then(() => {
                // show sweet alert
                swal({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Success!',
                    text: 'Your tutor profile has been updated!',
                    timer: 2500,
                    showConfirmButton: false
                });
            });
    },
}
```

});

Here's the inline-template I have:

```
<tutor-settings inline-template>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Tutor Profile</div>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': updateTutorProfileForm.errors.has('profile')}">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" v-model="updateTutorProfileForm.profile" style="font-family: monospace;"></textarea>

                    <span class="help-block" v-show="updateTutorProfileForm.errors.has('profile')">
                        @{{ updateTutorProfileForm.errors.get('profile') }}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <!-- Update Button -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                    @click.prevent="updateTutorProfile"
                    :disabled="updateTutorProfileForm.busy">
                Update
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Very new to Vue and trying to learn on the go! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you explain better? It is hard to understand what is your problem

Comment: @MU Please see my comment on the answer below, it doesn't look like the `$emit` is calling the `$on` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, firstly a `bus` should be used for communication between components, not within the components themselves, so `updateTutor` should be a method:

```
methods: {
    getTutor() {
        this.$http.get('/tutor/current')
            .then(response => {
                this.tutor = response.data;
                this.updateTutor();
            });
    },
    updateTutor() {
       this.updateTutorProfileForm.profile = this.tutor.profile;
    }
}
```

Now for a few other things to look out for:

Make sure you call your code in the order you want it to execute, because you appear to be `emitting` to the bus and then setting `this.tutor` but your function uses the value of `this.tutor` for the update of `this.updateTutorProfileForm.profile` so `this.tutor = response.data;` should come before trying to use the result.

You have a scope issue in your `$on`, so the `this` does not refer to `Vue instance` data but the function itself:

```
Bus.$on('updateTutor', function () {
    // Here 'this' refers to the function itself not the Vue instance;
    this.updateTutorProfileForm.profile = this.tutor.profile;
});
```

Use an arrow function instead:

```
Bus.$on('updateTutor', () => {
    // Here 'this' refers to Vue instance;
    this.updateTutorProfileForm.profile = this.tutor.profile;
});
```

Make sure you are **not** developing with the minified version of `Vue` from the `CDN` otherwise you will not get warnings in the `console`.

I can't see how you are defining your bus, but it should just be an empty Vue instance in the global scope:

```
var Bus = new Vue();
```

And finally, your `mounted()` hook is repeating the `created()` hook code, so it isn't needed. My guess is that you were just trying a few things out to get the update to fire, but you can usually do any initialising of data in the `created()` hook and you use  the `mounted` hook when you need access to the `this.$el`. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: You're a legend, thanks @craig_h!! Cheers for all the explanations, it's helped me understand a little better what's going on, and got it working :D

**edit** sorry but I can't upvote the comment because I don't have the rep points